# Explicit Lagrangian fibrations of a K3 surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, k3-surfaces, mirror-symmetry

I would like to look at the behaviour of the fibres of a Lagrangian fibration (such that at least some fibres are not special Lagrangian) $X\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ under the mean curvature flow (in relation to the Thomas-Yau conjecture). Here, $X$ is the quartic surface defined by
$$X=\{[z_0:z_1:z_2:z_3]\in\mathbb{CP}^3\mid\sum z_i^4=0\}$$
There is plenty of literature about elliptic fibrations, and hyper-Kähler rotations may be used to turn these into special Lagrangian fibrations for another Kähler structure. But special Lagrangian fibrations are uninteresting from this perspective, because special Lagrangians are stationary under the mean curvature flow. So are there any explicitly known Lagrangian fibrations of the quartic surface, with respect to the standard Kähler form induced by the Fubini-Study metric?